# Remove a character from a long string

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have the following string:

`https://example.com/get/ea34b8062cr2533eed0b4302e44d4090e26ae3c01bb1124292f3c970_1280.jpg`

I want just remove the character `s` from this part `https` and return the whole string again but without `s` character.

```
wxString imgURL = "https://example.com/get/ea34b8062cr2533eed0b4302e44d4090e26ae3c01bb1124292f3c970_1280.jpg";
imgURL.Remove(imgURL.find('s'));
this->m_textShowData->SetValue(imgURL);
```

Unfortunately, the previous code removes the `s` character but doesn't return the whole string again but it returns `http` only.

**How to remove the character `s` and then return the whole string without that character?**

Comment: imgURL.Replace("https", "http");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the erase function:

```
 imgURL.erase(4,1);
```

Comment: A nice example of the KISS principle!

Comment: It should be `imgURL.erase(4,1);`, the second argument isn't the end iterator but rather the amount of characters to remove. @LionKing

Comment: @LionKing, eddied, my fault should have run it

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#a497880b0bba35d3693883eef14fbdf36) Remove() function has overload where you can specify the number of characters you want to remove from given position.
So this should do the trick:

```
imgURL.Remove(imgURL.find('s'), 1);
```

But this function is preserved only for compatibility reasons and as the documentaion mentions, it should not be used in new code. Take a look at [erase()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#acb2c7985fb9550bb057b62bd6e5b4305) function instead, which has the same syntax as Remove()

Comment: That code removes the `s` character but just returns `http` only.

Comment: @LionKing Sorry, I put the `1` in a wrong parameter. Now it should be correct.